# Correct \printbibliography page number placement

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm writing my thesis and the university requires that my page numbers for my bibliography be on the top right corner. Unfortunately, the default `\printbibliography`command does not allow me to change the number placement. My setup is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, hyperref, setspace, fnpct, graphicx, fancyhdr, csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography/ref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\include{body/title}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\include{body/copyright}
\include{body/dedication}
\include{body/acknowledgements}
\include{body/abstract}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents} %Changes name from Contents to Table of Contents
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\begin{spacing}{1.92}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\include{body/physicalism}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %This is to change the \chapter functionality so the page number is in the top right corner.
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\include{body/conceivability}
\include{body/zombies}
\include{body/conclusion}
\end{spacing}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} %Adds Bibliography to toc
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

This results in the bibliography printing with a bottom center number:
[image: Bib]

I want it to be in the top right corner and I do not know how to make it do that.

Comment: You cannot redefine `\printbibliography` like that (and, in general, do not redefine it). Anyway, I cannot reproduce your problem. I get page numbers in the top right-hand side if I comment out the `\renewcommand` line.  (However, I do get errors stemming from fact that the MLA style has not been updated to the new version of `biblatex` --- but this is unrelated to the problem.)

Comment: @jon I'm not sure why, but my bibliography is coming out with page number at the center bottom. Any idea why?

Comment: Is that what's happening in the example you posted? To me that sounds more like a document where `\printbibliography` prints a `\chapter` as part of its job and `\chapter` calls `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: @jon I have edited my question.

Comment: You seem to have jumped a little too far in the other direction. This example cannot be compiled by others and clearly contains many packages unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should do what you want:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %This is to change the \chapter functionality so the page number is in the top right corner.
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

However, your file has put the command in the group

```
\begin{spacing}{1.92}
...
\end{spacing}
```

which localizes the redefinition of the `plain` pagestyle. So `\printbibliography` doesn't have a chance to see it. The solution is to move the redefinition out of the group (and to be aware of the effects of groups more generally).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla]{biblatex}%  
\usepackage{fancyhdr, setspace}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\cite{westfahl:space}

\begin{spacing}{1.92}

% uncoment the following line and comment out the other one below to see the difference
%\end{spacing}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %This is to change the \chapter functionality so the page number is in the top right corner.
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\end{spacing}

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: what you put up does work for me.

Comment: Correct. I'm not sure what the problem is with the real one.